# setDefaultReturnToken messes up syntax highlighting

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, jface

I'm developing an eclipse plugin with a custom text editor for which I want to provide syntax highlighting. Therefore I have implemented my own `RuleBasedPartitionScanner` and a respective `SourceViewerConfiguration`.
Everything is working fine when I don't mess with the defaultReturnToken of the PartitionScanner but when I try to set the default defaultReturnToken the syntax highlighting disappears.

My PartitionScanner:

```
public class SQFPartitionScanner extends RuleBasedPartitionScanner {

    public static final String SQF_COMMENT = "__sqf_Comment";
    public static final String SQF_CODE = "__sqf_Code";

    public SQFPartitionScanner() {
        IToken comment = new Token(SQF_COMMENT);
        IToken code = new Token(SQF_CODE);

        IPredicateRule[] rules = {
                //rule for multiLine comments
                new MultiLineRule("/*", "*/", comment),
                //rule for singleLine comments
                new EndOfLineRule("//", comment)
        };

        this.setPredicateRules(rules);

        this.setDefaultReturnToken(code);
    }

}
```

As the produced token of this no longer of type `IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` but instead of type `SQFPartitioScanner.CODE` I changed my `SourceViewerConfiguration` as followed (I only changed the `getPresentationReconciler()`-method):

```
public IPresentationReconciler getPresentationReconciler(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
        PresentationReconciler reconciler = new PresentationReconciler();

        DefaultDamagerRepairer dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(this.getKeywordScanner());
//      reconciler.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
//      reconciler.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
        reconciler.setDamager(dr, SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_CODE);
        reconciler.setRepairer(dr, SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_CODE);

        return reconciler;
    }
```

Is there something else I have to change for the syntax highlighting to work with the defaultReturnToken set to `SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_CODE`?

**EDIT:**
When I uncomment the lines

```
//      reconciler.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
//      reconciler.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

and comment

```
reconciler.setDamager(dr, SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_CODE);
reconciler.setRepairer(dr, SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_CODE);
```

I still get no syntax highlighting.
Because of that I suspect that the default token is not properly created because obviously it's not of type `IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` anymore but it's not of type `SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_CODE` neither

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

I think the problem may be that you need to add the two new content types to the getConfiguredContentTypes method in the new SourceViewerConfiguration.  I think you need to change SQFPartitionScanner to have the following lines at the top:

```
public static final IToken SQF_Comment_Type = new Token(SQF_COMMENT);
public static final IToken SQF_Code_Type = new Token(SQF_CODE);
```

Change the getConfigurationContentTypes to:

```
public String[] getConfiguredContentTypes(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
    return new String[] { IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE, 
        SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_Comment_Type, SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_Code_type };
}
```

And also remove the `comment` and `code` variables and replace them with the final static ones in SQFPartitionScanner, so you are always refering to the same instances.

**--------------------------------------------------------**

There seem to be some things defaulting to IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE and many dependencies on the contentType.  For example, in the PresentationReconciler it gets the damagers and reconcilers using the partition's content type.  The damagers are stored according to the contentType that you set with the repairer.  They are retrieved according to the type that the partitions report, and under some circumstances default to IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE:

```
if (document instanceof IDocumentExtension3) {
    IDocumentExtension3 extension3= (IDocumentExtension3) document;
    try {
        return extension3.getPartition(partitioning, offset, preferOpenPartitions);
    } catch (BadPartitioningException x) {
    return new TypedRegion(0, document.getLength(), IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

So I suspect that if you are going to have your own content type that you need to work it through the whole system properly.  That is I think you may have some inconsistency where some of the content thinks it is of the default type.

One way to see what is going on is to add the source jars for the relevant eclipse plugins to your environment and step through and see what happens in the PresentationReconciler regarding content types at run time.

Another approach is to temporarily uncomment the following lines from above:

```
//      reconciler.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
//      reconciler.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

So you have dr registered for both types and see if the highlighting returns.  If it does, this confirms that the issue is around the contentType coming back from the document.

Comment: when I uncomment these lines there is still no syntax highlighting reappearing...not even when I comment the two lines where I set the damager and repairer to the type `SQFPartitionScanner.SQF_CODE`

Comment: So my assumptions were wrong (again).  Did you make sure you modified `getConfiguredContentTypes()` in `SourceViewerConfiguration`  with the types that you have added?

Comment: Tried this one but `getConfiguredContentTypes()` expects an array of Strings and not an array of ITokens therefore I can't use the IToken constants there and just using the constants in `SQFPartitionScanner` did not help

Comment: I have my new contentTypes added in `getConfiguredContentTypes()` and I even tried to remove the `DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` or one of the other two but the result is the same in all cases